# Filtering by date resulting in error in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-redshift

Take this working query as an example, where `time_s` is the concatenation between a date and an hour, resulting in something like `2022-08-01T17:00:00Z`:

```
Select sum(previous.val)
from (
    SELECT val
        ,DATEADD(hour, LEFT(table1.hours, 2):: int, table1.date) as time_s
    FROM table1
    where 1=1
    and country='England') previous;
```

However, once I add a time filter based on `time_s` like:

```
Select sum(previous.val)
from (
    SELECT val
        ,DATEADD(hour, LEFT(table1.hours, 2):: int, table1.date) as time_s
    FROM table1
    where 1=1
    and country='England'
    and time_s < '2022-08-15T00:00:00Z') previous;
```

I got the following error and can't seem to find it's cause:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Invalid digit, Value ' ', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid digit, Value ' ', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
  code:      1207
  context:   
  query:     n
  location:  :0
  process:   query0_1_n [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Removing the `sum` function from the first select and keeping the filter by date, the query returns the resulting column.

Comment: I wonder whether it is a data issue? Is this an `external table`? If so, the source file might have some unexpected characters.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've extensively looked at the data and everything seems good. I've also noticed that the error rises whenever I use ```time_s``` within a where clause and apply some function to any column (like ```order by time_s```, ```sum(val)```, ```count(*)```. And no, it's not an external table. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of data that exhibit the problem, so we can attempt to reproduce your situation?